# Trying to store a contact entry in Android contacts

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have tried storing record in android phonebook with following code but failed.
I am posting the code I've tried,

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String nm, num;
    nm = t1.getText().toString();
    num = t2.getText().toString();
    ContentResolver c = getContentResolver();
    ContentValues record = new ContentValues();
    int iddd = TotalCount + 1;
    record.put("Contacts._ID", iddd);
    record.put("Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME", nm);
    record.put("Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER", 1);
    try {
        c.insert(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, record);
        ContentValues record1 = new ContentValues();
        record1.put("CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER", num);
        c.insert(CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, record1);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Contact saved2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to save contact", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
}
    This code when executed, gives an error. Failed to insert contact.
    Minimum sdk version is 8.
    Target sdk is 18.

    But don't know why it's causing this error.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code for storing contacts from your phone... by storing the contact phone in arrayList and the contact name in another arrayList :

=== Contacts.java ===

package com.showcontacts;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.ContentResolver;

import android.database.Cursor;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.provider.ContactsContract;

import android.util.Log;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.View;

```
public class Contacts extends Activity {

String phoneNumber;

ArrayList<String> phones = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> contact_name = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contacts, menu);
    return true;
}

/**** get all contacts ******/
public void getNumber(View v) {
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    String name;
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
            null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        name = cursor
                .getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        phoneNumber = cursor
                .getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        phones.add(phoneNumber);
        contact_name.add(name);// fill the Arraylist
    }
    cursor.close();// close cursor

    for (int i = 0; i < phones.size(); i++) {
        Log.d(contact_name.get(i) + i, (phones.get(i)));

    }
}
```

}

** activity_contacts.xml **

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Contacts" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:text="Button" 
     android:onClick="getNumber"
     />
```

** Dont forget to add permissions in your Manifest **

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

Best of luck